# mpirun tcp_peer_send_blocking: send() to socket X failed: Broken pipe (32)

Tags: linux, hpc

I am using a HPC composed by 4 machines (master, slave1, slave2, slave3 and slave4)
I try to run a script on a HPC structure :

```
mpirun -report-uri - -host master,slave1,slave2,slave3,slave4 --map-by node-np 50 hellompi
```

but I'm facing this error message :

```
657129472.0;tcp://10.1.1.1,10.1.2.1,10.1.3.1,10.1.4.1:54761
[charlotte-ProLiant-DL380-Gen10-slave1:07172] [[10027,0],1] tcp_peer_send_blocking: send() to socket 9 failed: Broken pipe (32)

ORTE was unable to reliably start one or more daemons.
This usually is caused by:

* not finding the required libraries and/or binaries on
  one or more nodes. Please check your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  settings, or configure OMPI with --enable-orterun-prefix-by-default

* lack of authority to execute on one or more specified nodes.
  Please verify your allocation and authorities.

* the inability to write startup files into /tmp (--tmpdir/orte_tmpdir_base).
  Please check with your sys admin to determine the correct location to use.

*  compilation of the orted with dynamic libraries when static are required
  (e.g., on Cray). Please check your configure cmd line and consider using
  one of the contrib/platform definitions for your system type.

* an inability to create a connection back to mpirun due to a
  lack of common network interfaces and/or no route found between
  them. Please check network connectivity (including firewalls
  and network routing requirements).
```

I am working on Ubuntu. Firewalls (ufw) are disabled on each machine. ssh login is okay, even in passwordless mode. Mpirun version is the same on each machine. Iptables is enabled.

The script I am trying to run is a simple fortran code :

```
program hello
include 'mpif.h'
integer rank, size, ierror, nl
character(len=MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME) :: hostname

call MPI_INIT(ierror)
call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierror)
call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierror)
call MPI_GET_PROCESSOR_NAME(hostname, nl, ierror)
print*, 'node', rank, ' of', size, ' on ', hostname(1:nl), ': Hello world'
call MPI_FINALIZE(ierror)
end
```

If I run in a couple of node, it works :

```
mpirun -report-uri - --mca oob_tcp_if_include 10.1.1.0/24 -host master,slave1 --map-by node -np 4 hellompi

4211277824.0;tcp://10.1.1.1:49281
node           0  of           4  on charlotte-ProLiant-DL380-Gen10-master: Hello world
node           2  of           4  on charlotte-ProLiant-DL380-Gen10-master: Hello world
node           1  of           4  on charlotte-ProLiant-DL380-Gen10-slave1: Hello world
node           3  of           4  on charlotte-ProLiant-DL380-Gen10-slave1: Hello world
```

It is the same with Master-Slave2, Master-Slave3, Master-Slave4

On master, ifconfig gives :

```
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:80:28:57:0f:7e  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      Packets reçus:0 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
      Octets reçus:0 (0.0 B) Octets transmis:0 (0.0 B)
      Interruption:16 

eno2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:80:28:57:0f:7f  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      Packets reçus:0 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
      Octets reçus:0 (0.0 B) Octets transmis:0 (0.0 B)
      Interruption:17 

eno3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:80:28:57:0f:80  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      Packets reçus:0 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
      Octets reçus:0 (0.0 B) Octets transmis:0 (0.0 B)
      Interruption:16 

eno4      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:80:28:57:0f:81  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      Packets reçus:0 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
      Octets reçus:0 (0.0 B) Octets transmis:0 (0.0 B)
      Interruption:17 

eno5      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:30:e0:31:b1:68  
      inet adr:10.1.3.1  Bcast:10.1.3.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
      adr inet6: fe80::5cfb:416e:a702:7582/64 Scope:Lien
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      Packets reçus:1038 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:966 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
      Octets reçus:186531 (186.5 KB) Octets transmis:106391 (106.3 KB)
      Interruption:32 Mémoire:e7800000-e7ffffff 

eno6      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:30:e0:31:b1:6c  
      inet adr:10.1.4.1  Bcast:10.1.4.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
      adr inet6: fe80::9451:8431:7010:46/64 Scope:Lien
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      Packets reçus:873 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:844 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
      Octets reçus:86934 (86.9 KB) Octets transmis:72778 (72.7 KB)
      Interruption:144 Mémoire:e8800000-e8ffffff 

ens2f0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:67:7c:06:5f:a8  
      inet adr:10.1.1.1  Bcast:10.1.1.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
      adr inet6: fe80::39c2:fdd5:930e:c253/64 Scope:Lien
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      Packets reçus:2195 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1425 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
      Octets reçus:1332614 (1.3 MB) Octets transmis:200100 (200.1 KB)
      Interruption:28 Mémoire:e3000000-e37fffff 

ens2f1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:67:7c:06:5f:ac  
      inet adr:10.1.2.1  Bcast:10.1.2.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
      adr inet6: fe80::91f5:53ce:378a:686e/64 Scope:Lien
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      Packets reçus:1644 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1385 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
      Octets reçus:379968 (379.9 KB) Octets transmis:211904 (211.9 KB)
      Interruption:123 Mémoire:e4000000-e47fffff 

ens5f0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:67:7c:06:5f:a0  
      inet adr:10.0.0.2  Bcast:10.1.0.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
      adr inet6: fe80::52e5:a943:831d:35f5/64 Scope:Lien
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      Packets reçus:9821 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:9230 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
      Octets reçus:983759 (983.7 KB) Octets transmis:2599111 (2.5 MB)
      Interruption:34 Mémoire:f0000000-f07fffff 

ens5f1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:67:7c:06:5f:a4  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      Packets reçus:0 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
      Octets reçus:0 (0.0 B) Octets transmis:0 (0.0 B)
      Interruption:165 Mémoire:f1000000-f17fffff 

lo        Link encap:Boucle locale  
      inet adr:127.0.0.1  Masque:255.0.0.0
      adr inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Hôte
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      Packets reçus:230476 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:230476 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
      Octets reçus:411579801 (411.5 MB) Octets transmis:411579801 (411.5 MB)
```

Slave1 : 10.1.1.1 (ens2f0),
Slave2 : 10.1.2.1 (ens2f1),
Slave3 : 10.1.3.1 (eno5),
Slave4 : 10.1.4.1 (eno6).

Informations about my ompi version are :

```
ompi_info
Package: Open MPI buildd@lgw01-57 Distribution
Open MPI: 1.10.2
Open MPI repo revision: v1.10.1-145-g799148f
Open MPI release date: Jan 21, 2016
Open RTE: 1.10.2
Open RTE repo revision: v1.10.1-145-g799148f
Open RTE release date: Jan 21, 2016
OPAL: 1.10.2
OPAL repo revision: v1.10.1-145-g799148f
OPAL release date: Jan 21, 2016
MPI API: 3.0.0
Ident string: 1.10.2
Prefix: /usr
Configured architecture: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configure host: lgw01-57
Configured by: buildd
Configured on: Thu Feb 25 16:33:01 UTC 2016
Configure host: lgw01-57
Built by: buildd
Built on: Thu Feb 25 16:40:59 UTC 2016
Built host: lgw01-57
C bindings: yes
C++ bindings: yes
Fort mpif.h: yes (all)
Fort use mpi: yes (full: ignore TKR)
Fort use mpi size: deprecated-ompi-info-value
Fort use mpi_f08: yes
Fort mpi_f08 compliance: The mpi_f08 module is available, but due to
                      limitations in the gfortran compiler, does not
                      support the following: array subsections, direct
                      passthru (where possible) to underlying Open MPI's
                      C functionality
Fort mpi_f08 subarrays: no
Java bindings: no
Wrapper compiler rpath: runpath
C compiler: gcc
C compiler absolute: /usr/bin/gcc
C compiler family name: GNU
C compiler version: 5.3.1
C++ compiler: g++
C++ compiler absolute: /usr/bin/g++
Fort compiler: gfortran
Fort compiler abs: /usr/bin/gfortran
Fort ignore TKR: yes (!GCC$ ATTRIBUTES NO_ARG_CHECK ::)
Fort 08 assumed shape: yes
Fort optional args: yes
Fort INTERFACE: yes
Fort ISO_FORTRAN_ENV: yes
Fort STORAGE_SIZE: yes
Fort BIND(C) (all): yes
Fort ISO_C_BINDING: yes
Fort SUBROUTINE BIND(C): yes
Fort TYPE,BIND(C): yes
Fort T,BIND(C,name="a"): yes
Fort PRIVATE: yes
Fort PROTECTED: yes
Fort ABSTRACT: yes
Fort ASYNCHRONOUS: yes
Fort PROCEDURE: yes
Fort USE...ONLY: yes
Fort C_FUNLOC: yes
Fort f08 using wrappers: yes
Fort MPI_SIZEOF: yes
C profiling: yes
C++ profiling: yes
Fort mpif.h profiling: yes
Fort use mpi profiling: yes
Fort use mpi_f08 prof: yes
C++ exceptions: no
Thread support: posix (MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE: no, OPAL support: yes,
                      OMPI progress: no, ORTE progress: yes, Event lib:
                      yes)
Sparse Groups: no
Internal debug support: no
MPI interface warnings: yes
MPI parameter check: runtime
Memory profiling support: no
Memory debugging support: no
          dl support: yes
Heterogeneous support: yes
mpirun default --prefix: no
MPI I/O support: yes
MPI_WTIME support: gettimeofday
Symbol vis. support: yes
Host topology support: yes
MPI extensions: 
FT Checkpoint support: no (checkpoint thread: no)
C/R Enabled Debugging: no
VampirTrace support: no
MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME: 256
MPI_MAX_ERROR_STRING: 256
MPI_MAX_OBJECT_NAME: 64
MPI_MAX_INFO_KEY: 36
MPI_MAX_INFO_VAL: 256
MPI_MAX_PORT_NAME: 1024
MPI_MAX_DATAREP_STRING: 128
MCA backtrace: execinfo (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA compress: gzip (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA compress: bzip (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA crs: none (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA db: print (MCA v2.0.0, API v1.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA db: hash (MCA v2.0.0, API v1.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA dl: dlopen (MCA v2.0.0, API v1.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA event: libevent2021 (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA hwloc: external (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component
                       v1.10.2)
MCA if: posix_ipv4 (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA if: linux_ipv6 (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA installdirs: env (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA installdirs: config (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA memory: linux (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA pstat: linux (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA sec: basic (MCA v2.0.0, API v1.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA shmem: posix (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA shmem: mmap (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA shmem: sysv (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA timer: linux (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA dfs: app (MCA v2.0.0, API v1.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA dfs: test (MCA v2.0.0, API v1.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA dfs: orted (MCA v2.0.0, API v1.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA errmgr: default_tool (MCA v2.0.0, API v3.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA errmgr: default_app (MCA v2.0.0, API v3.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA errmgr: default_orted (MCA v2.0.0, API v3.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA errmgr: default_hnp (MCA v2.0.0, API v3.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA ess: singleton (MCA v2.0.0, API v3.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA ess: slurm (MCA v2.0.0, API v3.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA ess: env (MCA v2.0.0, API v3.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA ess: tool (MCA v2.0.0, API v3.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA ess: hnp (MCA v2.0.0, API v3.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA filem: raw (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA grpcomm: bad (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA iof: tool (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA iof: hnp (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA iof: orted (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA iof: mr_hnp (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA iof: mr_orted (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA odls: default (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA oob: tcp (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA plm: isolated (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA plm: rsh (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA plm: slurm (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA ras: gridengine (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA ras: loadleveler (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA ras: slurm (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA ras: simulator (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA rmaps: round_robin (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA rmaps: mindist (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA rmaps: seq (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA rmaps: ppr (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA rmaps: rank_file (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA rmaps: staged (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA rmaps: resilient (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA rml: oob (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA routed: radix (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA routed: debruijn (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA routed: direct (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA routed: binomial (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA state: orted (MCA v2.0.0, API v1.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA state: app (MCA v2.0.0, API v1.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA state: dvm (MCA v2.0.0, API v1.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA state: staged_hnp (MCA v2.0.0, API v1.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA state: tool (MCA v2.0.0, API v1.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA state: hnp (MCA v2.0.0, API v1.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA state: staged_orted (MCA v2.0.0, API v1.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA state: novm (MCA v2.0.0, API v1.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA allocator: bucket (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA allocator: basic (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA bcol: basesmuma (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA bcol: ptpcoll (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA bml: r2 (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA btl: vader (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA btl: tcp (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA btl: openib (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA btl: sm (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA btl: self (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA coll: tuned (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA coll: self (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA coll: hierarch (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA coll: basic (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA coll: libnbc (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA coll: sm (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA coll: ml (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA coll: inter (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA dpm: orte (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA fbtl: posix (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA fcoll: ylib (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA fcoll: individual (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA fcoll: static (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA fcoll: dynamic (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA fcoll: two_phase (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA fs: ufs (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA io: ompio (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA io: romio (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA mpool: sm (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA mpool: grdma (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA osc: pt2pt (MCA v2.0.0, API v3.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA osc: sm (MCA v2.0.0, API v3.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA pml: v (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA pml: ob1 (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA pml: cm (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA pml: bfo (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA pubsub: orte (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA rcache: vma (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA rte: orte (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA sbgp: basesmsocket (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA sbgp: basesmuma (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA sbgp: p2p (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA sharedfp: sm (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA sharedfp: individual (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA sharedfp: lockedfile (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
MCA topo: basic (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.1.0, Component v1.10.2)
MCA vprotocol: pessimist (MCA v2.0.0, API v2.0.0, Component
                      v1.10.2)
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

For those who had a similar trouble, I partially solved it with help of OMPI team.
Please check https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/6293 for details.
Issue locked.